# marker (map pin shape) transform-origin

Tags: carto, cartocss

[image]

How can i move the center/origin of my marker image(map pin), so that my marker pin points always on the same point

(in CSS  transform-origin: center bottom;)

how can i achieve this in CARTO CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `marker-geometyr-transform` property that uses SVG trasform definitions. More details [here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties/#marker-geometry-transform-functions) and [here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties/#functions).

Something like

```
#point {
  marker-geometry-transform: translate(-2, -2);
}
```